How can I add custom method for \Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate?
I need to replace the method of getting the link this.getURL() with my custom method this.customMethod() in the confirmation email of the user during registration.
I have created a module:
registration.php
<?php
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
        'MyModules_Email',
        __DIR__
    );

etc/module.xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate" type="MyModules\Email\Model\Test" />
</config>

etc/di.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MyModules_Email" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Email"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>

Model/Test.php
<?php
    namespace MyModules\Email\Model;

    use Magento\Store\Model\Store;

     abstract class Test extends \Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate
     {
         public function getUrlToStorefront(Store $store, $route = '', $params = [])
         {
             return 'test';
         }
     }

But when I try to use my method in a letter template, nothing happens, it doesn't work, how can I fix this problem?

As Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate is an abstract class,
You need to ensure that your new class also remains abstract and implements all the abstract methods of the original class.
You can copy and paste the whole file code and modify it as per your override class without removing other functions.
Let me know if it works.

If I copy class fully and add my method - I get warning. Warning: Declaration of MyModules\Email\Model\Test::setTemplateFilter(MyModules\Email\Model\Template\Filter $filter) should be compatible with Magento\Email\Model\AbstractTemplate::setTemplateFilter(Magento\Email\Model\Template\Filter $
filter) in /repo/magento/app/code/MyModules/Email/Model/Test.php on line 744
